# How to force overwrite every file that was saved temporarily in memory in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Somehow I got into a state in VSCode where 1093 files are unsaved and I have to click "overwrite" for every single file one at a time.

[image]

I have to do CMD+S to save, then click "Overwrite" confirm for all 1000+ files, which is painful.

I got into this state by first changing string `values/book/file/code` to `values/book/code`, but then changing it to `values/book/file` before it finished completing the first operation (I think). Something like that.

How can I just "force overwrite" every file, so it gives me whatever string it ended up with? Then I can just do the batch find/replace operation again on whatever things I need to to clean up....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I just "force overwrite" every file, so it gives me whatever string it ended up with?

If you don't care what the outcome is (which sounds like is the case), instead of trying to overwrite everything, you can just discard all the conflicting changes. (I don't know how to overwrite everything, since VS Code intentionally asks you per-file to make a decision whether to overwrite when unsaved changes conflict with the file on disk).

You should have at least two options in the command palette:

- `View: Close All Editor Groups`
- `View: Close All Editors`

Both of these should prompt you whether or not you want to save your changes to any of the files that would be closed with unsaved changes, warning that changes will be lost if files are not saved, at which point you can select "Don't Save". (If you select save, the effect with respect to saving will be similar to if you use `Files: Save All`: it will fail and for each file with conflicts, create a notification asking to compare or overwrite).